# Phonegap covert GPS Timestamp to time

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

When using the time stamp returned by phonegaps gps function it looks like this:
1369395556895.94.

How do I convert that to a real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a "position" object that contain the gps coordinates, try with this one:

```
new Date(position.timestamp)
```